# mysql DATE() function

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have this query:
`SELECT DATE(start_date), tournamentID from track_tournaments`;

my result is this:

```
0:{DATE(start_date): "2017-01-07T00:00:00.000Z", tournamentID: 5}

1:{DATE(start_date): "2016-11-07T00:00:00.000Z", tournamentID: 4}

2:{DATE(start_date): "2015-11-07T00:00:00.000Z", tournamentID: 3}

3:{DATE(start_date): "2014-11-07T00:00:00.000Z", tournamentID: 2}

4:{DATE(start_date): "2013-11-07T00:00:00.000Z", tournamentID: 1}
```

Why is the date function not working properly to get rid of that pesky time?  It is not even set as datetime in the db to start, why is it there anyway? I have tried all kinds of syntax changes, and using as date.

Comment: Try using aliases like `DATE(start_date) as mydate`

Comment: which data type is your_start_date column ??

Comment: The output you posted is not generated by the MySQL server but by the client code you use to run the query. The MySQL [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function works properly and produces `2017-01-07`, `2016-11-07` and so on.

Comment: data type is date, not datetime, so I am confused why there is a time anyways.  @axiac, thanks, I will try and see what is reversing the DATE() format, just seems odd that it could add the time back onto the returned result

Comment: What software do you use to query the database? PHP, for example, provides the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class that, of course, includes fields for time components. It doesn't provide a class to store dates only, without time. Any software written in PHP that uses the `DateTime` class will produce similar results and the MySQL server or the query are not guilty.

Comment: The software you're using to print the result doesn't have date objects, it just has datetime. A date is just a datetime with time = 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT()` ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)).

> Formats the date value according to the format string.
>
> The following specifiers may be used in the format string. The %
>   character is required before format specifier characters.

For your query, you could use:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`start_date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `start_date`,
    tournamentID
FROM
    track_tournaments
```

Comment: kchason, that worked, thank you, I did not want to do this on the front end